# Retrofit: How to send a POST request with constant fields?

Tags: java, android, http, http-post, retrofit

I want to sent a simple POST request with one actual parameter:

```
@POST("/token")
@FormUrlEncoded
void extendSession(@Field("refresh_token")final String refreshToken);
```

But this request should also send some constant values requested by the server such as `client_id`, `client_secret` and `grant_type` which are constant and should not be part of the application API.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is matter of your approach. If you have the constants you can build a default Map of values required for your call. `@FieldMap` will be suitable for building a Map with all your required fields

```
private void extendSession(String token){
   Map params = buildDefaultParams();
   params.put("refreshToken", token);
   getRestAdapter().create(MyApi.class).extendsSession(params);
}
private Map buildDefaultParams(){
   Map defaults = new HashMap();
   defaults.put("client_id", CLIENT_ID);
   defaults.put("client_secret", CLIENT_SECRET);
   defaults.put("grant_type", GRANT_TYPE);
   return defaults;
}
  /**then you change your interface to this **/ 
    @POST("/token")
    @FormUrlEncoded
    void extendSession(@FieldMap() Map refreshToken);
```

Comment: This is what I ended up doing, though it is not an "elegant" solution.

Comment: There is a pending issue on Github, and I have linked this post there as well. https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/951

Answer (score 2):

A bit of an old question but after thinking about this myself for a while, this is what I came up with. I would love to hear any thoughts!

As is standard, I have my @POST defined in an interface called AuthWebservice:

```
interface AuthWebservice {

    @POST("oauth/token")
    @FormUrlEncoded
    fun refreshToken(
        @Field("grant_type")
        grantType: GrantType,

        @Field("client_id")
        clientId: String,

        @Field("client_secret")
        clientSecret: String,

        @Field("refresh_token")
        refreshToken: String
    ): Call<AccessToken>

}
```

**[NOTE: I'm using Dagger for dependency injection but the following logic would work no matter where you instantiate your webservice]**

In my NetworkModule I have the following to get an instance of AuthWebservice:

```
@Module
class NetworkModule {
    ...

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun providesAuthWebservice(
        retrofit: Retrofit
    ): AuthWebservice = retrofit.create(AuthWebservice::class.java)

    ...
}
```

**So here's my solution:**
I also include the following method definition inside AuthWebservice:

```
fun refreshToken(refreshToken: String): Call<AccessToken>
```

Note there are no annotations of any sort, and the method returns the same data type as the version that includes all of the arguments. This *will* compile, but obviously it will fail at runtime if you try to call it, something akin to the following:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: HTTP method annotation is required
>   (e.g., @GET, @POST, etc.).
>           for method AuthWebservice.refreshToken

Now I make a class called `AuthWebserviceWrapper` that takes an instance of `AuthWebservice`. In most cases it just calls the corresponding method on the base instance, *except* for the method I just added above:

```
class AuthWebserviceWrapper(private val base: AuthWebservice) : AuthWebservice {

    // Just call the base method.
    override fun refreshToken(
        grantType: GrantType,
        clientId: String,
        clientSecret: String,
        refreshToken: String
    ): Call<AccessToken> = base.refreshToken(
        grantType, 
        clientId,
        clientSecret, 
        refreshToken)

    // Call the base method with defaults!
    override fun refreshToken(refreshToken: String): Call<AccessToken> = 
        base.refreshToken(
            GrantType.REFRESH_TOKEN, // Default value 
            BuildConfig.MY_CLIENT_ID, // Default value 
            BuildConfig.MY_CLIENT_SECRET,  // Default value
            refreshToken
        )

}
```

And finally, back in `NetworkModule`, I wrap Retrofit's default implementation like so:

```
@Module
class NetworkModule {
    ...

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun providesAuthWebservice(
        retrofit: Retrofit
    ): AuthWebservice = AuthWebserviceWrapper(retrofit.create(AuthWebservice::class.java))

    ...
}
```

Now when I call `refreshToken` I get my method with default values:

```
class MyClass @Inject constructor(authWebservice: AuthWebservice) {

    fun doSomething(refreshToken: String) {
       val call = authWebservice.refreshToken(refreshToken)
    }

}
```

This does of course introduce some boilerplate, of which I am not a fan, but I think ultimately it's the cleanest way of making a webservice call without introducing the need for `@Body` or `@FieldMap`.

Anyway, that's my story and I'm sticking to it.

Answer (score 1):

You may use [Java Method Invocation Builder](https://github.com/tomasbjerre/java-method-invocation-builder) for this.

```
@GenerateMethodInvocationBuilder
public interface ServiceApi {
 @POST("/token")
 @FormUrlEncoded
 void extendSession(
  @Default("theToken") @Field("refresh_token") final String refreshToken,
  @Default("theId") @Field("client_id") final String clientId,
  @Default("theSecret") @Field("client_secret") final String clientSecret,
  @Default("theType") @Field("grant_type") final String grantType);
}
```

And then you can invoke the api like:

```
ServiceApiExtendedSessionBuilder.extendedSession()
 .withRefreshToken("theRefreshToken")
 .invoke(serviceApi);
```

Comment: `@Default` doesn't exist in `Retrofit`. Probably it is an annotation from that library.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a `String`, your interface could accept a `GrantType` object which has factory methods for different `grant_type`s. These factory methods would set the `client_id`, `client_secret`, and `grant_type` fields.

```
@POST("/oauth/token")
Call<Token> extendSession(@Body GrantType grantType);
```